# How to get the logs for a daemon process on Linux

Tags: linux, daemon, logfile

I started a daemon process like following:

```
./my-shell-script.sh -daemon other_params.cfg
```

Then it's all working normally except... I tried to look for logs and couldn't find it...

I tried to check under `/var/log/messages/` there is no folder called `messages`. All I can see under `/var/log` is below:

```
drwxrwxr-x  8 root   syslog   4096 May 19 15:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root   root     4096 May  9 02:00 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    16943 May 19 13:39 alternatives.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 May 19 13:39 apt
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm     19130 May 19 15:39 auth.log
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root     4096 May 19 13:09 azure
-rw-------  1 root   utmp    11136 May 19 15:39 btmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     8697 May 19 13:16 cloud-init-output.log
-rw-r--r--  1 syslog adm    264539 May 19 13:16 cloud-init.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Apr  9 14:01 dist-upgrade
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   123627 May 19 13:39 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      511 May 19 13:31 fontconfig.log
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm    182724 May 19 13:17 kern.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp   292292 May 19 14:39 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Oct 15  2017 lxd
drwxr-x---  2 root   adm      4096 Mar  6 15:43 samba
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm    304816 May 19 15:26 syslog
drwxr-x---  2 root   adm      4096 May 19 13:02 unattended-upgrades
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    18138 May 19 14:44 waagent.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp    10368 May 19 14:39 wtmp
```

Does anyone know where the logs would be ?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without more information. We have no idea what your script is or what it does from the information you have provided.

Comment: @it's a simple java hello world program running in a loop and printing "Hello world" message every 1 second. The output is going to stdout console.

Answer (score 0):

*By default,* daemon processes in Linux do not log their output anywhere. (The situation might be different on other operating systems, I don't know about other operating systems.)

Of course, this is useless, so in practice they usually do implement logging, at least optionally.

So you have to implementing logging yourself. There are two ways to implement logging in a Linux daemon process: syslog - which is not supported by Java - or just creating a file and writing to it. For the latter, professional programmers usually use a logging framework like log4j, logback or a wrapper like slf4j.

Comment: I could find my logs in `/var/log/syslog`. Though it was a ditry file with full of logs of different processes, I managed to find mine with regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you used `nohup` to make the process a daemon process, the log would be created as an ever-growing file `nohup.out` - as shown in the output of `nohup`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use rsyslog package in linux to do so which is useful for recording all kinds of logs which are generated by different component of linux system.

Inside the configuration you can uncomment the below line ,

## daemon.*           -/var/log/daemon.log

in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
Hope it works.

Comment: thanks, but it was already uncommented and I didn't find any daemon.log file in /var/log